# Assign an EventHandler from a control using it

Tags: c#, event-handling

kinda difficult to explain but is there a way to do something like:

```
control1.ShownEditor += EventHandler;

...

control2.ShownEditor += control1.ShownEditor; //wrong
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: you **cannot** use an `EventHandler` of a control's event and assign it to another event. So this isn't possible:

```
control2.ShownEditor += control1.ShownEditor; //wrong
```

The only way is to create an `EventHandler` separately and assign it to both the controls' event.

Another harmful solution could be extract the delegate via `Reflection`, but as I said it's actually dangerous, [look this answer by Hans Passant: Is it possible to “steal” an event handler from one control and give it to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293007/is-it-possible-to-steal-an-event-handler-from-one-control-and-give-it-to-anoth/293031#293031).

Answer (score 2):

Save your event to a EventHandler delegate.

```
EventHandler Myevent = () => {/*event handling code here*/};
```

Assign the event handler delegate to the control events

```
control1.ShownEditor += Myevent;
control2.ShownEditor += Myevent;
```

Comment: Thx Code but this misses the point. Point is to assign it from another control.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34990/Get-Delegate-from-Event-s-Subscription) to get bound `EventHandler`. 
As you have handler, you can then easily bind it to event.