# How do I remove all handlers from an event?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

```
Private Sub SetupToolStrip(ByVal ControlCollection As Control.ControlCollection)
        For Each aControl As Control In ControlCollection
            If TypeOf aControl Is System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip Then
                Dim ToolBar As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip = DirectCast(aControl, System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip)
                For Each Item As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem In ToolBar.Items
                    If Item.ToolTipText = "Print Report" Then
                           AddHandler Item.Click, AddressOf VerificDacaPrintam
                    End If
                Next
           End If
          If Not aControl.Controls Is Nothing Then SetupToolStrip(aControl.Controls)
       Next
 End Sub
```

But I want to remove all the events of `Item.Click` before I do:

```
AddHandler Item.Click, AddressOf VerificDacaPrintam
```

And the following does not work:

```
Item.Click = Nothing       

Dim del As [Delegate]() = Item.Click.GetInvocationList()
```

It says that "Click is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to "steal" an event handler from one control and give it to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293007/is-it-possible-to-steal-an-event-handler-from-one-control-and-give-it-to-anoth)

Comment: As a work around I hidden the button and added another.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this:

```
RemoveHandler Obj.Ev_Event, AddressOf EventHandler
```

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xz97kac%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: but i do not know the EventHandler's name. And when I try to get the list of all  eventhadlers with "Dim del As [Delegate]() = Item.Click.GetInvocationList() " it says that "Click is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event."

Comment: Any way i need the  EventHandler that handles the click event on the CrystalreportViewer print Button. Do you know anything about that?