# system.reflection.eventinfo does not contain definition for GetValue

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, reflection, checkbox

It's easy to obtain the values for the properties and fields or invoke methods but it has been difficult for me to display the Event handlers. I can't just use a GetValue function like I can for PropertyInfo.

I have tried following the instructions from https://web.archive.org/web/20131213074318/http://bobpowell.net/eventsubscribers.aspx - this works to display the events in *Windows Forms*.

However, this *will not work for Silverlight* because Silverlight does not have a 'EVENTHANDERLIST'.

Any ideas for how I can display the event VALUES in Silverlight?

I have tried this

```
namespace eventhandlers
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Type t = sender.GetType();
            FieldInfo fi = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            EventHandler eh = (EventHandler)fi.GetValue(sender);

            System.Reflection.EventInfo[] eventInfo = button1.GetType().GetEvents();                
            Delegate[] dels = eh.GetInvocationList();
            foreach(Delegate del in eh.GetInvocationList() )
            {
                string text = del.Method.Name;
                textBlock1.Text = text + ". " + textBlock1.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the error "FieldAccessException was unhandled by user code' and ''SilverlightApp1.MainPage.button1_Click (System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)' method 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase._isLoaded' failed to access the field." at

```
EventHandler eh = (EventHandler)fi.GetValue(sender);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to "steal" an event handler from one control and give it to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293007/is-it-possible-to-steal-an-event-handler-from-one-control-and-give-it-to-anoth)

Comment: no, this is not a duplicate of Is it possible to "steal" an event handler from one control and give it to another?

Comment: In Silverlight, you cannot use reflection to access private types and members. This limitation is created for security reasons.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So that must be why it's easy to obtain the values for the properties and fields or invoke methods but it has been difficult for me to display the Event handlers

Comment: Some of this code is invalid `FieldInfo fi = t.GetFields()` will not compile.  It needs to be `FieldInfo[] fi = t.GetFields()`