# Why can't I get the event handler of a LinkButton's event using reflection?

Tags: c#, events, reflection, eventhandler

I want to access the event handler of a `LinkButton`'s `Command` event, but in the snippet bellow `fieldInfo` is null.

```
LinkButton button = new LinkButton();
button.Command += (s, e) => { };
Type type = button.GetType();
EventInfo[] eventInfos = type.GetEvents(BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
foreach (EventInfo eventInfo in eventInfos)
    if (eventInfo.Name == "Command")
    {
        // fieldInfo is null
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = eventInfo.DeclaringType.GetField(eventInfo.Name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
        Delegate delegates = (Delegate)fieldInfo.GetValue(button);
        foreach (Delegate handler in delegates.GetInvocationList())
        {
            eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(button, handler);
            // or
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(button, handler);
            // or do whatever with handler
        }
    }
```

Code snippet was inspired from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103542/Removing-Event-Handlers-using-Reflection).

Why is `fieldInfo` null ?

Is there another way to get the event handler of a `LinkButton`'s `Command` event ?

Also [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/293031/1410908) sollution does not work on `LinkButton` using `Command` as the field name.

Comment: I assume the event has explicit add and remove handlers, and does not store its delegate in a dedicated field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [`LinkCommand` reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/a.html#f4f5ca856803a2ec):

`public event CommandEventHandler Command` is "magic".

`LinkCommand` uses the baseclass `UI.Control` and the events are stored in a `protected EventHandlerList Events`.

`LinkCommand` also has a private property called `EventCommand`, which appears to be used as the indexer for the `Events` list.

If I'm reading the source correctly, you'll need to extract `Events[EventCommand]` and cast it to `CommandEventHandler` like `LinkButton` does in `OnCommand`.

This also appears to be a common practice for classes using `UI.Control` as a base class.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try `EventCommand` as the field name. Massive fail. Anyway, I just tried it and it works. Awesome! Also I should probably learn to use the source code more (Yay OSS).

Comment: @Chris The reference source is not open source. You're allowed to look at it, but think twice before incorporating any part of it in your own software. Much has been open sourced, https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx, https://github.com/aspnet/, but I don't believe WebForms has.

Comment: Exactly why I gave an explicitly clear link, instead of quoting it, and explained what to do instead of writing code that may have been similar to the aforementioned reference code.